# nvd3.js sunburst chart - How to edit the tooltip?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, sunburst-diagram

I tried borrowing the `.tooltipContent(function(key, y, e, graph) { return 'Some String' })` and `.tooltip(function(key, y, e, graph) { return 'Some String' })` functions that are used in nvd3 pie charts, etc. But none of them seem to run for the Sunburst chart.

How do I customize the tooltip for the nvd3 sunburst chart?

Comment: Have you tried `chart.tooltip.valueFormatter(function(d){return d;});`

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer with some resources, if you can accept it to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting the tool-tip in the Sunburst Chart is different compared to the other NVD3 charts. [All NVD3 charts](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/site.html) have tool-tips built but for it but have different methods for changing them.

I just had a look at the NVD3 Suburst chart source code, and in [line 32](https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/sunburstChart.js#L32) I found a few methods that help us manipulate the tool-tip content.

Add the following code to make a custom tool-tip:

```
chart.tooltip.valueFormatter(function (d) {
    return d;
});
```

Hope it helps